# Using encode method in Python. Any workaround similar to map()?

Tags: python, encoding

I'm new to Python, and I can't find a workaround for this particular problem.

For every Chinese character in a list, I have to encode each character one by one.

```
for character in list:
    print character.encode('utf8')
```

Is there something similar to `map(function, characters)`, where I can apply the encoding method to all characters in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the characters into one string using [`str.join` (`unicode.join`)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and encode it.

```
u''.join(characters).encode('utf8')
```

---

```
>>> characters = [u'世', u'上']

>>> u''.join(characters)
u'\u4e16\u4e0a'
>>> print u''.join(characters)  # unicode
世上

>>> u''.join(characters).encode('utf-8')
'\xe4\xb8\x96\xe4\xb8\x8a'
>>> print u''.join(characters).encode('utf-8')  # str (encoded)
世上
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function/type [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Answer (score 2):

If this is really what you want to do (and I would think very carefully before rejecting falsetru's answer), you can do:

```
(character.encode('utf8') for character in list)
```

as a direct analogue to `map`. Use square brackets if you want a list instead of a generator.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use `map()`, [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) can give you a callable with one or more arguments "pre-filled":

```
from functools import partial
utf8 = partial(unicode.encode, encoding="utf8")
```

Example use:

```
>>> map(utf8, [u'毛', u'泽', u'东'])
['\xe6\xaf\x9b', '\xe6\xb3\xbd', '\xe4\xb8\x9c']
```